# The field "last_login" of User-model comes with Django cannot update automatically when I use "authenticate" func for user login

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user:
   return HttpResponse('success')
else:
   return HttpResponse('fail')
```

when the authentication pass, web will show "success",But the field 'last_login' of auth_user in database is still "null"

```
|id |password|last_login|is_superuser|fitst_name|last_name|email|is_staff|is_active|
             | <null>   |
```

I wanna update the field when login in and how should I solve it?